# Symfony EventDispatcher subscriber dont work

Tags: php, symfony, mediator, event-dispatching

The following code

```
use Application\Events\TransactionCreatedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;

class Transaction implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $date;
    protected $name;
    protected $address;
    protected $phone;
    protected $price_with_vat;
    protected $transaction_type;
    protected $receipt;
    protected $currency;


    protected function __construct($date, $name, $address, $phone, $price_with_vat, $transaction_type, $receipt, $currency)
    {
        $dispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        $dispatcher->addSubscriber($this);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(TransactionCreatedEvent::NAME, new TransactionCreatedEvent($date, $name, $address, $phone, $price_with_vat, $transaction_type, $receipt, $currency));
    }

    public static function CreateNewTransaction($date, $name, $address, $phone, $price_with_vat, $transaction_type, $receipt, $currency){
        return new Transaction($date, $name, $address, $phone, $price_with_vat, $transaction_type, $receipt, $currency);
    }

    private function onCreateNewTransaction($Event){
        $this->date = $Event->date;
        $this->name = $Event->name;
        $this->address = $Event->address;
        $this->phone = $Event->phone;
        $this->price_with_vat = $Event->price_with_vat;
        $this->transaction_type = $Event->transaction_type;
        $this->receipt = $Event->receipt;
        $this->currency = $Event->currency;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(TransactionCreatedEvent::NAME => 'onCreateNewTransaction');
    }
}
```

it suppose to dispatch a `TransactionCreated` event and get caught by the class itself and the `onCreatedNewTransaction` function get invoke in order to set the properties of the class.

The `Transaction` class instantiated like

```
$Transaction = Transaction::CreateNewTransaction('6/6/2016', 'John'....);
```

but when i debug the project the `$Transaction` object have `null` values. I set a `breakpoint` at `onCreateNewTransaction` method and I found that thus function does not get invoked.

**UPDATED**

*Problem solved*

`onCreateNewTransaction' should be public instead of private

Comment: I might be missing something, but why do you need event in this scenario?
Wouldn't it make more sense just to assign those properties in constructor?
Aside from that you should inject EventDispatcher instead of instancing it in constructor, this way you are creating fixed dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `CreateNewTransaction` is static, so no instances of `Transaction` is created and therefore  `__constructor` is never called.

This is regarding why this code doesn't work.

But, besides, I must say it's a total misuse of `Event` system of Symfony. Using framework (no `EventDispatcher` component), you must not create EventDispatcher yourself. It's beeing created by FrameworkBundle and you should only inject `event_dispatcher` service into whatever you need.

Otherwise, you can get lost very quickly with different scopes (each dispatcher has it's own subscribers and it's own events), and besides, it' s a waste of resources.

Comment: about your first concern my debuging session proves the opposite. The protected __constructor  get called with all the appropriate data injected. About your second concern I instantiate a single `EventDiaspatcer` at my composition root (aka bootstrap) and inject where it needs. This `new` at constructor  its only for legible purposes.

Comment: Anyway, when you create transaction like this `$Transaction = Transaction::CreateNewTransaction('6/6/2016', 'John'....);` nobody fires this event in your static method. And when you create an instance `Transaction` new transaction is being created, but with null values - which you see in your debugger

Comment: Just wanted to point out that there are times when creating your own event dispatchers is legitimate.  It can actually help to isolate your listeners from the rest of the framework listeners.  So don't rule it out completely.

Comment: After a lot of debugging I finally make it work. But my domain models now have a `Dispatcher`  dependency (all models have the same object injected). Do you guys think this constitutes a bad design?